# How to use a method from other class Java Android onClick?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

Is there any way to call a method of another `class` in the `onClick` of a `button`?

I need call `myClass.myMethod()` in the `onClick`, but say its no in the main

my onClick button
`android:onClick="textToVoice.listenVoice"`

My class, dont finished:

```
public class TextToVoice extends MainActivity{
public void listenVoice(){
    this.makeVoice();

}
public void downloadVoice(){


}
private void makeVoice(){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), this.makeUrl(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
private String makeUrl(){
    Editable phstr = super.textVoice.getText();
    String textUrl = phstr.toString();
    if (textUrl.contains(" ")){
        textUrl = textUrl.replace(" ", "+");
    }
    return textUrl;
}
}
```

and the main:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected EditText textVoice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.textVoice =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textVoice);
    TextToVoice textToVoice = new TextToVoice();
}
......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected EditText textVoice;
Button button;
TextToVoice textToVoice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ln_dialog);
    textVoice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textVoice);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textToVoice = new TextToVoice(MainActivity.this,textVoice.getText().toString());
            textToVoice.listenVoice();
        }
    });

}


public class TextToVoice extends MainActivity {
    String textString;
    Context context;

    public TextToVoice(Context c ,String s) {
        textString = s;
        context = c;
    }

    public void listenVoice() {
        makeVoice();
    }

    public void downloadVoice() {
    }

    public void makeVoice() {
        Toast.makeText(context, makeUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private String makeUrl() {

        if (textString.contains(" ")) {
            textString = textString.replace(" ", "+");
        }
        return textString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not informed many details, but here it goes

Comment: so its working or not for you ?

Comment: No. I edited the post with more information

Comment: Now check it will work for you.

Comment: i have changed the ln_dialog to activity_main, but crashed...

Comment: what is your exception ?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lucalacerda.droidvoice/com.lucalacerda.droidvoice.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: take button control in your layout and bind it

Comment: i'm using thow image buttons, for diferent methods. 
but if i put a button, return same error, and caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: you have to initialize all image button than after use it

Comment: Sorry, im new in Java. How?

Comment: Take ImageButton in your layout screen , give ID to it and use following code in your java
    `ImageButton imageButton ;
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
            }
        });`

Comment: The app opening, but after click in button, get the erro:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

/And thanks for you help!

Comment: please provide me code . I will correct it

Comment: the main: http://pastebin.com/3bGVF1uQ

Comment: http://pastebin.com/M4ZcMZGP and check in manifest file that you have to declare activity in it.

Comment: same error... and my manifest its ok. http://pastebin.com/Xcamei0k. I have edited with you code.

Comment: I think you forgot to define any permission in manifest file . anandraj16992@gmail.com mail me your complete code

Comment: you receive the email?

Comment: check your mail i correct that code

Comment: For the sake of other people rather than just the asker, please input your comment and explanation if possible in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the method in the other class as public and static and you can then use it as 
YourClass.method()

Comment: but i need use this. to refer a other method... how to now?

Answer (score 0):

Why does your TextToVoice class extend the MainActivity. Android buttons require implementations of the View.OnClickListener interface. Try implementing the afore mentioned interface rather than extending MainActivity. Pass the context of the class to the constructor and work in the method specified. See if it works.